# Random freezes with Ubuntu 16.04.1 on Lenovo g50-45

Tags: lenovo

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on Lenovo g50-45

After working for 3-4 hrs it hangs/freezes randomly. Mouse and keyboard working but after stopping the unresponsive program it freezes again and again.

I did a clean install.

CPU is an AMD chipset (A8-6410 with Raedon R5 Graphics).

Random freezes is due to my graphics card Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0).
As I read Ubuntu 16.04.1 does not support AMD gpus.
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please follow: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes, and post any results here.

Comment: Does it hang when opening too many tabs on the browser or switching from full-screen mode to normal more or it hangs even if there is no reason ?

Comment: its hangs when there two many tabs any browser.i unable to do anything  then.. i see this daily.let us know solution.